# php inside literal script - .tpl

Tags: javascript, smarty, json

How can i make a `json_encode` inside a literal javascript block? Basically this is smarty template.

```
 {literal}
    <script>
        function openWin() {
            var O = {php} echo json_encode($obj);{/php}; // syntax error         
            alert(O);
        }
    </script>
 {/literal}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I had to fiddle with a Smarty template but I think you'd have to close the literal tag to run your php code.  If you get an error, try removing the `echo` too - I can't remember if it's implicit or not when inside a smarty tag.

```
{literal}
  <script>
    function openWin() {
      var O = {/literal}{php}echo json_encode($obj);{/php}{literal};       
      alert(O);
    }
  </script>
{/literal}
```

Addendum:

Smarty syntax for echoing variables can also accommodate "filters" (ie. functions)

```
{$obj|json_encode}
```