# Display variable inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I want to change a hyperlink inside a script with a variable. It's the FB SDK, i want to display the SDK in the language the user chose on my website.

The variable is `{$lang_fb}` and returns the correct result (here:en_US) if I use it in normal php.

If I use the variable inside a script on a plain HTML page there is no result.

The script:

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/{$lang_fb}/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=01234567890";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
<script>
```

results in the identical code in the page

What can I do?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you're using PHP to generate the file.

Comment: @Blazemonger, why did you remove part of the question?

Comment: @Blazemonger you are making something with the question that is prohibited in stackoverflow. Causes conflicts with the author's intention

Comment: The removed part was identical.

Comment: But he also removed the `<script>` tags.

Comment: If the snippet is NOT in a template/PHP page, then the `{$lang_fb}` will not be processed. If you know the language before loading this html, you can set a cookie and use that in place of the var

Comment: The removed part is identical, **but** causes sense loss.

Comment: I will remove my answer because you can't make that you try. A plain HTML file does static, it's a markup language not a programming language. So you can't insert variables or another thing that in a programming language you can. If you have a plain HTML you need to put static values where you are using variables.

Comment: Please, stop editing the question. There are 5 editions.

Comment: You can make the web server parse html pages as if they are php, and therefore embed php script inside an html file.  If you were to do that then the answer from @MarcosPérezGude is correct.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [php inside literal script - .tpl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143561/php-inside-literal-script-tpl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soluition:

```
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/{/literal}{$lang_fb}{literal}/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=1234567890";
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a PHP script, you need to put the php tags or escape the string.

### Way one

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/<?php echo {$lang_fb} ?>/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=01234567890";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

### Way two

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/".{$lang_fb}."/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=01234567890";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

If you don't share more code we can't view what happens.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The page is in html, not in php.

Comment: Or you aren't explain fine your problem or is impossible that you can render a variable in HTML. HTML is a markup language, not a programming language.

Comment: Yes, but it's really a html (.tpl) file. And the variable works inside html.

Comment: Please, explain better your system of templates. Maybe if you use underscore or something similar you can achieve that with the javascript parser

Comment: the variable will be generated inside a settings.php with

$smarty->assign('lang_fb', $lang_fb);

Comment: if it's php, your only solution is making a php file, not an html file. Sorry.

Comment: OK thks. I'm just wondering why {$lang_fb} works in the tpl file outsinde the script without any php mask

Comment: Sorry but if we don't know more details about your template system and your programming method we can help you better. Good luck!

Comment: @mplungjan ok, you are assuming that OP uses smarty template system. I was asked a lot of times since the oP writes the question and he doesn't answer to me. What if he uses Underscore, Boilerplate, or another template system?

Comment: hence I did not close it as duplicate but posted a comment

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Yes it's smarty. I have no experience with that, so I didn't knew.

Comment: Ronny, see the @mplungjan comment, that is your solution

Comment: Yes I saw that, thanks. Looks good, i deal with it. At this time it's not working. Do I have to change the script, and can i use the {$lang_fb} in the fb src link?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a file extension, that is not PHP related, you need to [setup php to process this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687217/2441442).

For apache you can do this with the file `.htaccess`:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .tpl
```

Of course you also need to [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) the Facebook SDK which creates `{$lang_fb}`.

Answer (score -2):

`$lang_fb` is a php variable and will not work in javascript. Are you embedding your script tag within php file? If yes then you can simply use the following:

```
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/"+<?php echo $lang_fb; ?>+"/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=01234567890";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: That's totally wrong. `"+<?php ... +"` will produce a javascript variable.